# Neo4j event handling plugin + logging

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-plugin

I am new to neo4j and I want to develop a plugin that registers changes in database to a log, for now i only want log transaction data. I am using maven with java 17 to build the jar and Docker to deploy neo4j with the latest image (5.10.0).

The plugin looks like this:

Class to handle logging events:

```
public class Neo4jTriggersPlugin implements TransactionEventListener<Object> {
    private final Log log;


    public Neo4jTriggersPlugin(DatabaseManagementService dbms, LogService lgsvc) {
        this.log = lgsvc.getUserLog(Neo4jTriggersPlugin.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeCommit(TransactionData transactionData, Transaction transaction, GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCommit(TransactionData transactionData, Object o, GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService) {
        log.info("Transaction committed" + transactionData.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterRollback(TransactionData transactionData, Object o, GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService) {
    }
```

```
public class LifecycleManagement extends ExtensionFactory<LifecycleManagement.Dependencies> {
    private Log logger;
    @Override
    public Lifecycle newInstance(ExtensionContext extensionContext, final Dependencies dependencies) {
        return new LifecycleAdapter() {
            LogService logService = dependencies.log();
            private Neo4jTriggersPlugin triggersPlugin;

            @Override
            public void start() {
                System.out.println("STARTING trigger watcher");
                triggersPlugin = new Neo4jTriggersPlugin(dependencies.getGraphDatabaseService(), logService);
                dependencies.getGraphDatabaseService().registerTransactionEventListener("neo4j", triggersPlugin);
            }

            @Override
            public void shutdown() {
                System.out.println("STOPPING trigger watcher");
                dependencies.getGraphDatabaseService().unregisterTransactionEventListener("neo4j",triggersPlugin);
            }
        };
    }

    interface Dependencies {
        DatabaseManagementService getGraphDatabaseService();
        LogService log();
    }

    public LifecycleManagement(Log log) {
        super(ExtensionType.DATABASE, "registerTransactionEventHandler");
        this.logger = null;
    }
```

I found example [here](https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neo_listens).
I went through neo4j documentation about logging, procedures, extensions etc.

After I compile and build the .jar of the above plugin, I copy it into `var/lib/neo4j/plugins/` directory and restart the container. Then I run some cypher queries and I do not see any info written in a log. Also I have mounted the /logs and /data/database as volumes.

I would appreciate if someone could explain how this is done corretly or point me to a good source of information. Thanks.

Comment: Does the example plugin (which is pretty old) work as-is? If so, see what you are doing differently.

Comment: @cybersam I have tried using @Context annotation with the `org.neo4j.logging.Log` which should inject the logger provided by the database, did not work, perhaps ther is something with compiling/building .jar? I am using build dependencies provided here from official Neo4j template

Comment: The [Context](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/extending-neo4j/procedures/#injectable-resources) annotation is only documented to work with [user-defined procedures](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/extending-neo4j/procedures/) that are explicitly invoked via Cypher. Your plugin does not define a procedure.

Comment: I have annotated LifecycleManagment class with `@ServiceProvider` and now I am getting prints on the docker log with stdout and it is initializing the plugin, I am also getting comitted transaction in the callback. I am still trying to figure out how to correctly wire through logger @cybersam

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @matej See my answer for a workaround to implementing the logging yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the logger from the `Dependencies` , you can check an example here

https://github.com/ikwattro/neo4j-transaction-event-listener-extension/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ikwattro/neo4j/tx/MyExtensionFactory.java#L31

Answer (score -1):

As a workaround, your plugin can invoke the extended APOC [apoc.log](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/5/overview/apoc.log/) procedures (e.g., [apoc.log.info](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/5/overview/apoc.log/apoc.log.info/)) to log to `neo4j.log` on the server.

Also, instead of writing your own commit-triggered plugin, you may want to use [APOC's trigger procedures](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/background-operations/triggers/) instead.